# What is $E|\langle A\rangle|$?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, expectation

Suppose $A$ is a random subset of $S_n$, such that each element of $S_n$ independently belongs to $A$ with probability p. What is the expectation of $|\langle A\rangle|$?

The case with $p = 1$ ($E|\langle A\rangle| = n!$) is quite obvious, however, I do not know, how to deal with the situation when $0 < p < 1$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $p=0$ then $E=1$, as the identity is always an element of any subgroup.

Comment: The expected size of $A$ is $n!/p$. If this is at least $2$, then the probability that $\langle A \rangle = A_n$ or $S_n$ approaches $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Sorry I mean the expected size of $A$ is $n!p$.

Comment: What's $\langle A\rangle$ and $|\langle A\rangle|$, btw?

Comment: @Alex $\langle A\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by the set $A$, and $|\langle A\rangle|$ is the order of this subgroup.

Comment: @Derek Holt This is not quite accurate.  If $p=c/n!$ and $c$ is a constant, then there is a positive probability (roughly $e^{-c}$) that $S$ is empty.

Comment: @KevinCostello Yes, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that two random permutations generate $S_n$ is $1 - o(1)$; see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435952/probability-that-two-randomly-chosen-permutations-will-generate-s-n). Hence as long as $p = \omega(1/n!)$, the probability that $A$ generates $S_n$ is $1 - o(1)$, and in that case the expectation of $|\langle A \rangle|$ is $(1-o(1))n!$. In more detail, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
E|\langle A \rangle| &= \Pr[|A|=0] + \exp \Theta(\sqrt{n/\log n}) \Pr[|A|=1] + (1-o(1))n! \Pr[|A| \geq 2] \\ &= 
(1-p)^{n!} + \exp \Theta(\sqrt{n/\log n}) n!(1-p)^{n!-1}p + (1-o(1))n! (1 - (1-p)^{n!} - n!(1-p)^{n!-1}p).
\end{align*}
$$
using the formula for the expected order of a permutation, due to [Goh and Schmutz](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~schmutze/PAPERS/musn.pdf). When $p = c/n!$ for constant $c$, this gives
$$
E|\langle A \rangle| \approx e^{-c} + ce^{-c} \exp \Theta(\sqrt{n/\log n}) + (1-e^{-c} - ce^{-c})n!.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is a random subset of a finite group $G$, such that each element of $A$ independently belongs to $G$ with probability $p$ (in your case $G = S_n$). One can see that $\forall H \leq G (P(A \subset H) = (1 - p)^{|G| - |H|}$. It is also true, that $P(A \subset H) = \Sigma_{K \leq H} P(\langle A \rangle = K)$. Thus, $P(\langle A \rangle = H) = \Sigma_{K \leq H} \mu(H, K)P(A \subset K) = \Sigma_{K \leq H} \mu(H, K)(1 - p)^{|G| - |K|}$, where $\mu$ is the Moebius function for subgroup lattice of $G$. Thus we have the formula:
 $$E|\langle A \rangle| = \Sigma_{H \leq G} \Sigma_{K \leq H} |H|\mu(H, K)(1 - p)^{|G| - |K|}$$

That is one of the possible forms of answer, despite it is quite hard to anyhow simplify it, as one must know the structure of subgroup lattice of $G$ to calculate the Moebius function (In your case it is especially hard as the subgroup lattice of $S_n$ is not well described).