# Cyclic subgroup of $A_5$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Consider $A_{5}$ group and let $a,b \in A_5 $ .

> Find probability of the subgroup generated by a and b.
> $\langle a, b\rangle$ , be
> cyclic group .

I think if $a=1$ then we have 60 cyclic subgroup because $A_5$ has 60 elements, also 59 cyclic subgroup for $b=1$ so we have 60+59 cyclic subgroups and probability is $\frac{119}{60×60}$ is this true?

Comment: The number of cyclic subgroups is a lot smaller. For example, if $a=(12345)$, then $a$ and all its powers generate the same subgroup. There are six cyclic subgroups of order five, ten of order three and fifteen of order two.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen . I think we must only find a,b and this is not necessary to find this subgroups are isomorphic or not .

Comment: I think that this entry is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435952/probability-that-two-randomly-chosen-permutations-will-generate-s-n

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2598998/104041)

Comment: What I was getting at is that if $a$ is 5-cycle then $\langle a,b\rangle$ is cyclic for five choices of $b$. If $a$ is a 3-cycle, then $\langle a,b\rangle$ is cyclic for three choices of $b$ etc. You compute the weighted average. I was not counting isomorphism types, I was counting *distinct* cyclic subgroups.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to the question is no that is not true. The correct answer, as given by C Monsour is 3/40.

Answer (score 1):

The orders of elements of $A_5$ are

$Order \quad   Num\, Elements
\\
\\  1    \quad\quad\quad\quad       1
\\  2   \quad\quad\quad\quad            15
\\  3     \quad\quad\quad\quad          20
\\  5     \quad\quad\quad\quad          24$

Since none of these numbers are composite, $<a,b>$ will  be cyclic precisely when one of these elements is a power of the other.  This is because if two elements generate a cyclic group and one is not a power of the other, then the cyclic group has composite order (in a group of prime order all elements are powers of any non-identity element, and the identity alone doesn't generate a group of prime order).  But $A_5$ has no cyclic subgroups of composite order as it has no elements of composite order.

Since the problem does not state whether $a$ and $b$ are drawn with or without replacement, it's somewhat ambiguous, and it actually makes a rather large difference: $<a,b>$ is substantially more likely to be cyclic if drawn with replacement.  However, in usual mathematical usage, one does not assume $a \ne b$ unless explicitly stated, so technically we should answer the problem as though these are drawn with replacement.

Therefore, out of $3600$  (i.e., $60\cdot 60$) cases, we have

$60$ cases of $a=1$ and $b$ any.

$30 = 2\cdot 15$ cases of $o(a)=2$ and $b\in <a>$

$60 = 3 \cdot 20$ cases of $o(a) = 3$ and $b\in <a>$

$120 = 5 \cdot 24$ cases of $o(a) = 5$ and $b\in <a>$

So the probability you are looking for is $270/3600$, or $7.5\%$

Also note that if you want the "draw without replacement answer" you can simply subtract the $60$ cases of $a=b$ from both the numerator and the denominator, to get $210/3540=7/118$, or just a hair over $5.9\%$.