# Is this equation $(n+1)~x^{2n+1}-n~x^{2n}-n=0$ solvable in radicals for some $n \geq 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, roots

Consider this polynomial equation:

$$(n+1)~x^{2n+1}-n~x^{2n}-n=0,~~~~n \geq 2,~~~n \in \mathbb{N}$$

It's related to another question of mine, but I don't think the context matters here.

I'm interested in the positive real solution. For $n=1$ the positive real solution is $x=1$.

What I want to ask:

> Is it possible for the above equation to be solved in radicals for some $n \geq 2$ and what is the explicit expression for the real positive solution?

If we substitute $x=\frac{1}{y}$, we obtain the equation:

$$y^{2n+1}+y-\frac{n+1}{n}=0$$

Comment: I think for $n$ prime you can essentially apply this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/837970/128967