# How can I see that the tower of extension collapse when we have the square root of discriminant is in the base field?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, discriminant

[image]

I am considering the tower of extension of $E$ which is the splitting field for any degree $3$ irreducible polynomial over $F$. It is said that: if the square root of discriminant (denote the discriminant as $\Delta$ here) is in the base field $F$, then the tower of extension collapse to the tower $F(\alpha)-F$ on the right hand side.

May I please ask how does it happen? I think it comes from the fact that as $F(\alpha_1,\sqrt{\Delta})=F(\alpha_2,\sqrt{\Delta})=F(\alpha_3,\sqrt{\Delta})=E$. So once we have $\sqrt{\Delta}\in F$, once we adjoint any root of the polynomial, we have whe whole splitting field.

But if the argument above is true, how can I prove that $F(\alpha_i,\sqrt{\Delta})=E$ for any root $\alpha_i$ of the degree-$3$ irreducible polynomial? And also may I please ask if $F(\alpha_i,\sqrt{\Delta})=E$ holds for any irreducible polynomial of any degree? How may I prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be an irreducible cubic polynomial with roots $\{\alpha_i\}$ and  discriminant $D = \displaystyle \prod_{i \neq j} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)^2$.

**Claim**: If $\sqrt{D} \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \cong A_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$ is the splitting field.  Otherwise, if $\sqrt{D} \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \cong S_3$ and we have a tower of proper inclusions $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \sqrt{D})$, with the latter the splitting field.

**Proof**: Suppose that $\sqrt{D} \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Given that $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ consists of all automorphisms of the splitting field of $f$ that also fix $\mathbb{Q}$, it must be the case that $\displaystyle \sqrt{D} = \prod_{i \neq j} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)$ is fixed by all the elements of $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$.  Each element of $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ is determined by its action on the roots of $f$.  Any permutation of the roots of $f$ that decomposes into an odd number of transpositions will change the sign of $\sqrt{D}$.  Thus, $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ can only contain even permutations, meaning it is a subgroup of $A_3$ (having at most $3$ elements).  Since adjoining any root of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ yields a degree-$3$ extension, it is forced that such an adjunction *is* the splitting field, and in fact $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \cong A_3$.

Now suppose $\sqrt{D} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.  Since $D \in \mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ is a degree-$2$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Consider the tower $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}, \alpha_1)$, where $\alpha_1$ is a root of $f$.  We cannot have $\alpha_1 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ because $\alpha_1$ is an algebraic element of degree $3$.  Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}, \alpha_1)$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $6$.  Since the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial is a subgroup of the permutation group on its roots, we must have $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \subseteq S_3$.  This constricts the degree of the splitting field to a maximum of $6$, and from this we can see that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}, \alpha_1)$ **is** the splitting field of $f$ with Galois group necessarily isomorphic to $S_3$.

---

Now, in general, if $\alpha_1$ is a root of a polynomial $f$ and $\deg(f) = n > 3$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \sqrt{D})$, **will not** be the splitting field of $f$.  In particular, this field has as degree *at most* $2n$, but [all the symmetric groups $S_k$ appear as Galois groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Symmetric_and_alternating_groups) of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$.  If $\text{Gal}(f) \cong S_k$, its splitting field is of degree $k!$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  For a concrete example, any polynomial of prime degree $\geq 5$ with exactly $2$ complex roots [has Galois group $S_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837948/proving-that-a-polynomial-is-not-solvable-by-radicals/837970#837970).

Comment: If $\sqrt{D}= (\alpha_1-\alpha_2)(\alpha_1-\alpha_3)(\alpha_2-\alpha_3) \in \mathbb{Q}$, since $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$ is the splitting field. Its Galois group is of order $3$, thus automatically $C_3=A_3$