# Quintic Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've recently been watching some *3blue1brown* videos and I watched one about the *Monster set* in group theory. Now, I have my questions about that but most I'm curious about something else he mentioned, namely *quintic equations*. I probably spelled that wrong, but what I mean is, an equation one-step above a quadratic equation. For example, something that looks like this: $$ 6x^{5}+3x^{4}+3x^{3}+5x+6=0 $$ So, my question is, what is the universal formula for solving an equation like this. And, where exactly does it come from?

Comment: There is no universal formula for a quintic equation, as shown in Galois theory, which involves group theory.  And by the way, quintic is one degree higher than *quartic*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No universal formula *with only radicals*. Otherwise, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Beyond_radicals

Comment: People will tell you that there is no general formula for this - indeed they have at the time of writing this comment. However, the accurate statement is that there is no general formula in radicals to express the roots of a quintic - some new idea must be involved. Of course some quintics do have (radical, rational, integer) solutions, but not all. And even for quartics it is not so much the solution which is useful to know as the method.

Comment: Since you are referring to a video, it would be best to ask that at youtube.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Spot on, and great link.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks for that correction, I wasn't really thinking about that when I was writing this...

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula to find the roots of a general quintic polynomial. The Abel-Ruffini Theorem is the formal statement of this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Answer (score 0):

There is no general formula to solve a quintic, but the proof that no such formula exists requires some machinery. It is one of the famous results of a branch of abstract algebra called Galois theory. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/837970/691096) for more details.

Comment: There are methods for solving quintics, just none using radicals alone.