# Is there a general form for infinite nested radicals of degreen n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, nested-radicals

Say we have the infinite nested radical
$$\sqrt[n]{a + \sqrt[n]{a + \sqrt[n]{a + \cdots}}}$$

When $n = 2$, this evaluates to $\frac{1 + \sqrt{4a + 1}} {2}$, which is the positive root of the equation $x^2 - x - a = 0$.

When $n = 3$, this evaluates to $\sqrt[3]{\frac{9 a + \sqrt{81 a² - 12}} {18}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{9 a - \sqrt{81 a² - 12}} {18}}$, which is the positive real root of the equation $x^3 - x - a = 0$.

When $n = 4$, this evaluates to $\frac{1} {2} \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\frac{9 + \sqrt{768x³ + 81}} {18}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{9 - \sqrt{768x³ + 81}} {18}}} + \frac{1} {2} \sqrt{-\sqrt[3]{\frac{9 - \sqrt{768x³ + 81}} {18}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{9 + \sqrt{768x³ + 81}} {18}} + \frac{2} {\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\frac{9 + \sqrt{768x³ + 81}} {18}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{9 - \sqrt{768x³ + 81}} {18}}}}}$, which is the positive real root of the equation $x^4 - x - a = 0$.

In general, nested radicals of degree $n$ with $n > 1$ give the positive real root of the equation $x^n - x - a = 0$.

Is there a formula or process that will output the expression for a given value of $n$? Is an algebraic solution even possible for $n > 4$? I worked out the three examples given here using WolframAlpha and GeoGebra, but what was quick and simple for $n = 2$ was slower for $n = 3$ and quite tedious for $n = 4$, and WolframAlpha doesn't even show an algebraic solution for $n = 5$.

Comment: Related: [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving quintic equations of the form $x^5-x+A=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786161/solving-quintic-equations-of-the-form-x5-xa-0)

Comment: @markvs It confirms that there is no solution in radicals for the degree-five case, so it seems it does put the brakes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=5$, $a=1$, the Galois group of [$x^5-x-1$ is $S_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637796/galois-group-of-x5-x-1-over-bbb-q). So a root cannot be expressed in radicals starting with rational numbers by the Galois theorem, so no algebraic solution is possible if $a=1,n=5$.

For arbitrary $a$, $n=5$ and more general solutions see [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786161/solving-quintic-equations-of-the-form-x5-xa-0)